# Change database in SqliteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Is there a way to change what database an SQLiteOpenHelper object uses without having to force every class that uses the helper to replace their instance of the class?

The reason why I'm changing the database is because I have some live data and some offline data in two separate databases with identical table structures. I update the offline data and then swap them, allowing me to lock the offline database on big inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to acces to your database with only one instance 
it's look like

```
    public class SingletonDemo {
        private static SingletonDemo instance = null;
        private SingletonDemo() { // do what you want here}
        public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized (SingletonDemo.class) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = new SingletonDemo();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }

...
// Add all the class function you need here

    }
```

This is thread safe and can be use every where you need.